# How to return string with all instances of a string replaced by another string ( Java )

Tags: java, string, while-loop

In this program, I am trying to return a new string that is composed of new letters that were added and old letters if the didn't fit the constraints. I am stuck in terms of I don't know how to fix my code so that it prints correctly. Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Here are some examples:

str: "asdfdsdfjsdf", word: "sdf", c: "q"

should return "aqdqjq", I'm getting "asdqqq"

str: "aaaaaaaa", word: "aaa", c: "w"

should return "wwaa", as of right now my code only returns "ww"

```
public static String replaceWordWithLetter(String str, String word, String c) 

    String result = "";
    int index = 0;

    while (index < str.length() )
    {
        String x = str.substring(index, index + word.length() );
        if (x.equals(word))
        {
            x = c;
            index = index + word.length();
        }
        result = result + x;
        index++;
    }
    if (str.length() > index)
    {
        result = result + str.substring(index, str.length() - index);
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be overcomplicating this. You can simply use the [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) method:

```
public static String replaceWordWithLetter(String str, String word, String c)  {
    return str.replace(word, c);
}
```

Which when called as:

```
replaceWordWithLetter("asdfdsdfjsdf", "sdf", "q")
```

Produces the output:

```
aqdqjq
```

---

The problem with your current method is that if the substring is not equal to `word`, then you will append as many characters as there are in `word`, and then only move up one index. If you will not be replacing the sequence, then you only need to append one character to `result`. Also it is much more efficient to use a `StringBuilder`. Also as noted if the `String` is not divisible by `word.length()`, this will throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsError`. To solve this you can use the `Math.min()` method to ensure that the substring does not go out of bounds. Original method with fixes:

```
public static String replaceWordWithLetter(String str, String word, String c)  {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int index = 0;

    while (index < str.length() )
    {
        String x = str.substring(index, Math.min(index + word.length(), str.length()));
        if (x.equals(word))
        {
            result.append(c);
            index = index + word.length();
        }
        //If we aren't replacing, only add one char
        else {
            result.append(x.charAt(0));
            index++;
        }
    }
    if (str.length() > index)
    {
       result.append(str.substring(index, str.length() - index));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: I found another issue in my code...when the while loop reaches the sixth index of string "aaaaaaaa" the end would be nine except the length is eight. How would I make it so it exits the while loop before I encounter this error?

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix to my issue using @GBlodgett's code:

```
    String result = "";
    int index = 0;

    while (index <= str.length() - word.length() )
    {
        String x = str.substring(index, index + word.length() );
        if (x.equals(word))
        {
            result = result + c;
            index = index + word.length();
        }
        else {
            result = result + x.charAt(0);
            index++;
        }
    }
    if (str.length() < index + word.length())
    {
        result = result + (str.substring(index));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `String.replaceAll()` method.
example:

```
public class StringReplace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "aaaaaaaa";
        String fnd = "aaa";
        String rep = "w";

        System.out.println(str.replaceAll(fnd, rep));
        System.out.println("asdfdsdfjsdf".replaceAll("sdf", "q"));
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
wwaa
aqdqjq
```

Comment: replaceAll is for replacing using regex.

Comment: I learnt it just few minutes back. I was misinterpreted by name `replaceAll`. Are there any performance differences between `replace` and `replaceAll`

Comment: The performance problems are not the issue. Interpretation of regaular chars as  regex chars is the issue